# Loop trought json with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

This is response from my php script:

> [{"name":"sss","vote_up":2,"vote_down":0,"report":2},{"name":"sdsad","vote_up":2,"vote_down":0,"report":2},{"name":"sssssss","vote_up":2,"vote_down":0,"report":2},{"name":"sssssss","vote_up":2,"vote_down":0,"report":0},{"name":"sss","vote_up":1,"vote_down":0,"report":1},{"name":"TEST","vote_up":1,"vote_down":0,"report":1},{"name":"asdsa","vote_up":1,"vote_down":0,"report":0},{"name":"ssssssssss","vote_up":1,"vote_down":0,"report":0},{"name":"TEEST","vote_up":1,"vote_down":0,"report":0},{"name":"sssssssssssssssssssss","vote_up":1,"vote_down":1,"report":1},{"name":"asdsadsa","vote_up":1,"vote_down":0,"report":1},{"name":"KOmentar","vote_up":1,"vote_down":0,"report":1},{"name":"ssssssssss","vote_up":0,"vote_down":1,"report":1}]

how can I catch that data with jQuery, here is my try but not working:

```
 $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url:"/bylikes",
            data:{task:true,comment:commentID,reply:replyID},
            success: function( data ){
                repObj = JSON.parse(data);
                 $.each(repObj,function(index,item){
                    alert(item.name+ " - "+item.report)
                 }); 
               //$('#fullList').html(""+data+"");
            }


    });
```

Comment: What is not working? Do you get the `alerts()`? Is your `$.ajax()` not being called? Is `data` not being returned? It is difficult to tell what is wrong if you don't give more information.

Comment: alerts not working if each loop... But if I do like this alert(data) it return json I put above...

Comment: What do you want to alert? I mean what is the output you want?

Comment: I want to get names from json.

Comment: Have you tried just looping through the `data`, as it might already be parsed as json -> `$.each(data,function(index,item){...`

Comment: Yes, then get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '762' in 
             
             
[{"name":"sss","vote_up":3,"vote_down":0,"report":4},{"name":"sdsad","vote_up":3,"vote_down":0,"report":2},{"name":"sssssss","vote_up":2,"vote_down":0,"report":2},...

Comment: Try specifying `dataType: "json"` or using jQuery's `$.parseJSON()` -> `repObj = $.parseJSON(data);`. Also, `method:"POST",` should be `type:"POST",`